# Font styles problem

Tags: qgis

i have problems with Font Styles in qgis.
I have created fonts symbols in my system but when i open the same qml in an other pc the fonts is rong. I try to export my symbols in xml but nothing.
please help me.

**Edit:**

[image]

The right symbols is this, when I open the qgs in the other all symbols are wrong. Maybe does not exist the font in the other pc. How can I import them?

Comment: Are the fonts on the other computer?